# "cordova platform add android" fails with unexpected error

Tags: android, ubuntu, cordova

i am trying to install Phonegap on Ubuntu 13.04, i have installed the Android SDK with all available Packages, but running the following command:

```
cordova platform add android
```

fails with an unexpected error:

```
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. An unexpected error occurred: "$ANDROID_BIN" create project --target $TARGET --path "$PROJECT_PATH" --package $PACKAGE --activity $ACTIVITY &>/dev/null exited with 1
Deleting project...
```

I have set the PATH Variables for Android (tools / platform-tools) and java and ant are installed.

Why does this happen? How can i get a more detailed error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PhoneGap 2.5.0 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239110/phonegap-2-5-0-issue)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

have you tried running command with sudo?
it could be a permissions issue.

If still not working, try running it using verbose mode i.e. sudo -d cordova...

In case this is due to activity name whitespaces, see comments for this answer.

There is an issue reported in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4198, for which I've sent a pull request to remove whitespaces https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/pull/39.

Comment: I've tried sudo, that didn't help. But the create tool from the phonegap package (lib/android/bin/create) works, so i can now have fun with html/js apps. thank you Ryan and José for your answers.

Comment: if you're using the hello world example, I think that there's a problem in there.
I was just trying to reproduce, and found that it tries to create an activity using Hello World as its name... this was the final error I've got to make it work. (after the permission issue)
What I did, was to change the script to use HelloWorld as activity name.

Comment: You're right, it's working without the whitespace, silly, silly thing.

Comment: it's probably a good idea to make comments on the issue or the pull request... or both, so the fix is included.

Answer (score 4):

As @José said, the "hello" example doesn't work because spaces are not allowed.
Changing it to "HelloWorld" solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

remove the space in between name tags  in config.xml

MyAppName< name>

Comment: thank you, the other answers said to remove the whitespace, only yours said where to do it

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using debian wheezy, the example from: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface does not work with this error:

> [Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project. An unexpected error occurred: "$ANDROID_BIN" create project --target $TARGET --path "$PROJECT_PATH" --package $PACKAGE --activity $ACTIVITY &>/dev/null exited with 1
>   Deleting project...
>   ]

After adding $JAVA_HOME (Java sun, with openjdk did't work) and $PATH the andriod sdk path to `.../sdk/platform-tools:../sdk/tool`

The solution in my case was the project name:

**The example that doesn't work:**

> cordova create HelloWorld com.example.hello "Hello World"

**THIS works:**

> cordova create HelloWorld com.example.hello HelloWorld

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your package and project names are correct, following the `com.mycompanyname.myappname` format without any numbers or dashes.

[Here's the issue being tracked by PhoneGap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/1091).

Comment: The package name is correct, i am using the hello world example: cordova create hello com.example.hello "Hello World". Also thanks for the github link, but it doesn't seems that they found an solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the create file (phonegap-2.7.0/lib/android/bin/create) with textEdit, there is a line that lists

`ANDROID_BIN=”${ANDROID_BIN:=$( which android )}”`.

The “which android” is the cause of the issue

If you replace this line with the full path to your android tools (SDK), it should resolve the issue. It looked like this:

```
ANDROID_BIN=/Users/cswjs/Documents/Dev/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/android
```

OR try modify ~/.bash_profile using `open ~/.bash_profile` to full PATH

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Users/cswjs/Documents/Dev/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/cswjs/Documents/Dev/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

And use `cordova create foo com.example.foo foo` to create new project named foo. Make sure project name should be same.

Hope this could help someone!

Answer (score 0):

IN my case there are many places in create script where u need to remove  >null to see real logs.     and i finally resolved my issues by 
sudo chown -R sachinsharma ~/.cordova